# Create adapter from array(AutoCompleteTextView)

Tags: java, android, arrays, adapter

help me please with set adapter for `AutoCompleteTextView`

MyCode:

```
arr = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.site_array);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
     MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,arr);
url_str.setAdapter(adapter);`
```

When i try set array with loop normally filled
and not empty Autocomplete results do not appear.

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
   arr[i] = Utils.getHost(History.getLinkElementFromIndex(MainActivity.this,i));
   Log.v("TEST_1",arr[i]);
}

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
     MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,arr);
url_str.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: I think you code should work. What exactly is the issue? You results are not displayed when you type in the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find Answer.
You can't create ArrayAdapter with 1000+ strings in array.
Maximal string count == 500. This works for me good.